# npm run build react js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

Below is the error I am facing.
dharm@LAPTOP-877D2J39 MINGW64 /c/Windows/System32/contactmanager (master)
$ npm run build

> contactmanager@0.1.0 build C:\Windows\System32\contactmanager
>   react-scripts build

Failed to compile.

EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\Windows\System32\contactmanager\build'

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! contactmanager@0.1.0 build: `react-scripts build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the contactmanager@0.1.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\dharm\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2018-12-06T10_22_25_                                                                                                                475Z-debug.log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir

Seems like some permission issue, can you try opening the terminal as an **administrator** & try building the application. There should be an option to 'Run As Admin' when you right click on the bash icon.

Comment: Glad to hear bud! :-)